# redux store alternative with customized store in react

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm studyin this code of a react component:

https://github.com/algolia/react-instantsearch/blob/master/packages/react-instantsearch-core/src/core/createStore.js

```
export default function createStore(initialState) {
  let state = initialState;
  const listeners = [];
  function dispatch() {
    listeners.forEach(listener => listener());
  }
  return {
    getState() {
      return state;
    },
    setState(nextState) {
      state = nextState;
      dispatch();
    },
    subscribe(listener) {
      listeners.push(listener);
      return function unsubcribe() {
        listeners.splice(listeners.indexOf(listener), 1);
      };
    },
  };
}
```

I was surprise this code don't use , but a own store? someone can me explain about this code? this a way to use global store and don't use redux-store?

this lines:

```
listeners.forEach(listener => listener());

          return function unsubcribe() {
            listeners.splice(listeners.indexOf(listener), 1);
          };
```

what does mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simplified implementation of Redux-like store. It doesn't involve other Redux entities like middlewares or reducers.

`setState` does exactly what it's expected from it, so does [`subscribe`](https://redux.js.org/api/store#subscribe).

`listeners.forEach(listener => listener())` notifies listeners that a state was updated.

`return function unsubcribe() {...}` returns a function to unsubscribe a listener from state updates.